# Dns does not contain a definition for `GetHostEntry'

Tags: linux, powershell, syntax, mono, .net-core

I am coming [from](https://askubuntu.com/q/1007058/45156) `powershell` to `Mono`:

```
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ ls
hello.cs
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ cat hello.cs 
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
    }
}

thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ mcs hello.cs 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ mono hello.exe 
Hello Mono World
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ dotnet --version
2.1.4
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
thufir@dur:~/mono$
```

I am looking to do something like this `powershell` one-liner:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name localhost -Type ANY | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

but from `Mono`.  Here's [what I have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3771856/262852) so far:

```
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ ls
dns.cs  hello.cs
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ mcs dns.cs 
dns.cs(10,35): error CS0117: `Dns' does not contain a definition for `GetHostEntry'
dns.cs(5,14): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
dns.cs(11,28): error CS0118: `System.Net.IPAddress' is a `type' but a `variable' was expected
dns.cs(11,28): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
thufir@dur:~/mono$ 
thufir@dur:~/mono$ cat dns.cs 
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System; 

public class Dns
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World");
        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        Console.WriteLine (IPAddress);  
    }
}

thufir@dur:~/mono$
```

Do I have the correct version for `dotnet`?  Are the imports correct?

Am I not declaring and instantiating the `ipaddress` variable correctly, with the correct type?

Comment: You simply missed assembly references, as `System.Net.Dns` lives in another assembly which you need to pass to `mcs` via argument. Learn `mcs` man page for more information. If you really is learning how to program in C#, give up the raw `mcs` approach. Most people use a project (.csproj) and MSBuild to write C# programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own class name `Dns` is overriding the System.Net namespace. Try for example this:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System;

public class MyDns
{
    static public void Main()
    {
           Console.WriteLine("Localhost: ");
           IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
           Console.WriteLine(ip);
    }
}
```